# Let ∂(X) be a 3-edge cut of a cubic graph G. G is 3-edge-colourable if and only if both G \ X and G \ X' are 3-edge-colourable, where X' := V \ X.

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a 3-edge-colorable cubic graph. Let X be a set of vertices such that the size of ∂(X) is 3.
How do I guarantee that G-X is 3-edge-colorable? I know the cut will remove 3 edges, but what does it guarantee that G-X will continue with the property? I'm having a hard time on this part.

Comment: What does $G/X$ mean? How is $X:=V\setminus X$ even possible?

Comment: Sorry, I'll arrange it. Actually it's G \ V.

Comment: G \ V means a new graph obtained from the vertex exclusion of the set V.